# Autocomplete-light registry issues

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views, django-autocomplete-light

I am trying to install autocomplete-light into one of my forms. I keep getting this error:

```
Institution not registered, you have registered: ['InstitutionAutocomplete']
```

I have not declare or registered InstitutionAutocopmlete anywhere in my code so I don't know how I could have triggered this error.

I have the following form:

```
class AddUserAccountsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """
    Form for adding new user financial accounts.

    """
    required_css_class = 'required'
    name = forms.ModelChoiceField(required=True, queryset=Institution.objects.all(), widget=autocomplete_light.ChoiceWidget('Institution'))
    user_accounts_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'User Name'}), label="")
    user_accounts_password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Password'}), label="")

class Meta:
    model = Institution
    fields = ('name','user_accounts_name', 'user_accounts_password',)
```

This is in my autocomplete_light_registry.py:

import autocomplete_light

```
from models import Institution

autocomplete_light.register(Institution,
    search_fields = ['name'],
    attrs={
        'placeholder':'Find your institution',
        'data-autocomplete-minimum-characters':1,
    },
    widget_attrs={
        'data-widget-maximum-values':4,
        'class':'modern-style',
    },
)
```

Here is my html. The error is triggered when the code runs {{ form.as_p}}.

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'jquery.js' %}">
</script>
{% include 'autocomplete_light/static.html' %}

<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
</form>
```

urls.py is:

```
url(r'^profile/add_user_accounts/', UserAccountsUpdate.as_view(), name='add_user_accounts'),
```

Answer (score 1):

In your form you have to use 'InstitutionAutocomplete' instead of 'Institution'

```
name = forms.ModelChoiceField(required=True, 
                              queryset=Institution.objects.all(), 
                              widget=autocomplete_light.ChoiceWidget('InstitutionAutocomplete'))
```